# StreamAPI: how to use StreamAPI properly

Tags: java, list, dictionary, collections, java-stream

I have a conceptional question in using the StreamAPI properly:

Normally StreamAPI is used to convert one dataformat in another format, like for example convert from list into a map:

```
List<Object> text.stream()...collect(Collectors.toMap(...))
```

But is it allowed to use a third variable like for example:

```
List<Object> listA;
Map<Object,String> map;

List<String> listB=listA.stream().map(o -> map.get(o)).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question that can be easily answered by trying to compile the code and seeing what happens.

Comment: map() it is functional interface, it is not variable)

Comment: @ЮлийЩербак No, `map()` is a method that takes a functional interface as a parameter. In the example code the `o -> map.get(o)` lambda is used as the parameter.

Comment: That line can even be simplified to use a method reference `.map(map::get)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's allowed, but is should be effectively final then, that means
 a non-final local variable whose value never changes after initialization.